# Адаптивная верстка для современных смартфонов

Tags: html, css, mobile, веб-дизайн

Первоначально сайт был написан под статический размер в 1200px.
Со временем дизайнер нарисовал 3 варианта: 1920, 800 и 320 пх.
Для размера в 1920px ничего переделывать не стал, использовал то что было под 1200.

**Вот структура моего css:**

```
//Сначала старые стили, их использую если размер больше 800px

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    //здесь стили для экранов не больше 800px
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   //здесь стили для экранов не больше 320px
}
```

На ноутбуке все работает нормально, адаптивность сделал еще и резиновой если так можно назвать. При смене экрана браузера - вид изменяется. Но **задача была в том чтобы сайт отображался нормально на планшетах и смартфонах**. Но сейчас в современных мобильных дэвайсах разрешение зачастую больше разрешения ноутбуков, говорю про HD и FHD. Сайт на смартфоне с разрешением FullHD отображается как на компьютере и не читабельный. Можно ли как-то отображать на телефоне с разрешением допустим экрана в ширину 1920 контент как для монитора с разрешением 320 или 800? Или как вообще решают эту проблему? Не хотелось бы снова переписывать css

Comment: Так помимо min-width и max-width есть еще куча медиа запросов. В твоем случае используй device-pixel-ratio и resolution. Почитать тут например https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо viewport задать, чтобы телефоны 640 считали что они 320px. У меня так стоит:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что доктор приписал. На фул хд в вертикальном положении дает 320, а в горизонтальном 800

Comment: Только я не стал бы отключать пользователям возможность масштабирования.......

Comment: Ок, это уберу. Заказчик хочет чтобы на смартфонах разрешение было как 320, а на планшетах как для 800. Но вот получилось так, что на смартфоне с фул хд и хд определяется разрешение больше 320 и отображается дизайн для 800(если планку поднять от 320 до 400 в медиа запросе тогда на смартфоне отображается этот дизайн, то есть смартфон определяет в диапазоне от 320 до 400). Я так понимаю это все относительно и для разных смартов с одинаковым разрешением но разными размерами экрана дизайн может быть разный и все упирается в dpi.

Comment: Делайте резину, я пришел к примерно такому набору: телефон вертикально < 450, телефон горизонтально < 800, планшет вертикально < 900, планшет горизонтально > 900